# How to jump to associated test method with Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

If I have a method and one or a few tests associated with that method, can I jump quickly from the method to the test's implementation using keystroke or whatever?

I'm using visual studio 2010 and resharper beta 6. I can use "find usages" but that would pull out everything, not just tests. And I need to jump to tests very often and usually quick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Use Find Usages, then, in the Find Results window, apply a filter called "Unit test usages". Disclaimer: this is off the top of my head, need to check tomorrow if it works exactly this way.

Option 2: Use [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) which has a keystroke to show all tests covering a specific method.